# Caching not stored using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory in DOT NET

Tags: c#, caching, dotnet-httpclient, http-caching

I'm using Microsoft Extensions Caching Memory, but it is not storing data on cache.
My code:

```
public class MyMemoryCache<TItem>
    {
        private MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        private ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, SemaphoreSlim>();
        public async Task<List<TItem>> GetOrCreate(object key, List<TItem> createItem)
        {
            List<TItem> cacheEntry;
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
            {
                SemaphoreSlim mylock = _locks.GetOrAdd(key, k => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
 
                await mylock.WaitAsync();
                try
                {
                    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
                    {
                        // Key not in cache, so get data.
                        cacheEntry = createItem;
                        _cache.Set(key, cacheEntry);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    mylock.Release();
                }
            }

            return cacheEntry;
        }
    }
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
ISqlQueries query = new SqlQueries();    
var _openCases = new MyMemoryCache<MyListDTO>();
var openedCases = _openCases.GetOrCreate("GetMyInfo", query.Displaydata()).Result;
```

QUERY

```
public List<MyListDTO> DisplayData()
{
     HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
     hch.Proxy = null;
     hch.UseProxy = false;
     var client = new HttpClient(hch);
     var result = client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
}
```

I am able to retrieve data successfully from server but it's calling the server all the time due to lack of caching storage. what I am missing, thanks.

Comment: `query.DisplayData()` is evaluated, then its result is passed to `GetOrCreate`. So, yes, it will be executed every time regardless of the cache. To prevent that from happening, you might want to pass a `Func<List<TItem>>` instead.

Comment: I just edited my first comment. I'd pass a Func, that creates the list only if it's a cache miss.

Comment: BTW: You are mixing sync and async all over the place. Try and go "async all the way". Otherwise you risk tripping over some deadlock issues sooner or later. I also advise to not create new HttpClients all the time. Make use of HttpClientFactory and DI (if you can).

Comment: BTW: You may also want to explore Polly's [CachePolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#cache)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the code like this:

```
public async Task<List<TItem>> GetOrCreate(object key, Func<Task<List<TItem>>> createItem)
{
    List<TItem> cacheEntry;
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
    {
        SemaphoreSlim mylock = _locks.GetOrAdd(key, k => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));

        await mylock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
            {
                // Key not in cache, so get data.
                cacheEntry = await createItem(); // will only actually fetch data
                                                 // on cache miss
                _cache.Set(key, cacheEntry);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            mylock.Release();
        }
    }

    return cacheEntry;
}
```

Usage:

```
var openedCases = await _openCases.GetOrCreate("GetMyInfo", () => query.Displaydata());
```

Query:

```
public async Task<List<MyListDTO>> DisplayData()
{
     HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
     hch.Proxy = null;
     hch.UseProxy = false;
     var client = new HttpClient(hch);
     // ^^ Please do NOT create new HttpClients all the time.

     return await client.GetAsync(url,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Now it goes first to cache method and it hit cache.set but again is not saving it, as I refresh page and still call server.

Comment: Hmm, ... Actually, I don't find a `Set` overload that takes key, value. The only 2-Args `Set ` takes a CacheItem and a Policy...